# How can I get VSCode to find gmp.h after it has been successfully installed on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, gmp

After installing and following the instructions for [GMP](https://gmplib.org/manual/Installing-GMP) (using mingw64 since I am on windows) and verifying the installation was correct using `make check` I tried running the following code in VSCode using the command `g++ -g \path\file.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp -o \path\file.exe`:

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mpz_class a,b,c;
    cout << "Hello World\n";
    a = 1234;
    b = "5678";
    c = a+b;
    return 0;
}
```

But get the error `error: 'mpz_class' was not declared in this scope`. So the include path in VSCode is incorrectly set up or the installation was messed up. I am wondering how to fix this: is this VSCode's includePath (compilerPath is not set up), an installation issue (I could not determine the default install location for windows systems since everything I found was for Linux), or is there something else I missed? I saw a flag for `./configure` that was `--enable-cxx` but I wanted to ask before running `make clean` and retrying with that flag turned on since it takes forever.

I feel like this is something dead simple since I cannot find any help from googling.

Thank you for any help!

EDIT: I have tried running the code not in VSCode and it still has the same issue so I am not so sure it's VSCode.

Comment: It's true that, very often, trying to cram Linux/Unix originated software, like gcc, into a foreign operating system that wasn't designed to run Linux/Unix-originated code, turns out to be a major, major time sink. Even experienced developers will struggle with this, not to mention those who are new to C++. Most of the time it takes much less time to simply install Linux from scratch, and get a fully working, fully configured, modern C++ compiler. It took me just an hour and a half, last time. Now, I'd just buy a Lenovo laptop with preloaded Linux. How much time did you already spend on this?

Comment: About 10 minutes of set up (not including install time, but that's not relevant since I could do other things). The rest of time (about 20 minutes) was spent googling. Buying a new laptop is probably out of the question. I'd prefer to use Windows but if I have to I will spin up a VM to ease my problems.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This problem is unrelated to MinGW, and I was able to reproduce it on my Ubuntu. I've heard you say it before, but to be fair, I had a nice experience with MinGW so far (specifically, MSYS2). Everything works out of the box, the repos have up-to-date compilers and a bunch of prebuilt libs, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about GMP, but you seem to include the wrong header.

`#include <gmpxx.h>` worked for me.

Comment: I hate my life. They need better examples on their website.

Comment: @evader110 The right header is mentioned at the beginning of https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General , I don't know where you were looking.

Comment: @MarcGlisse At the top of [here](https://gmplib.org/manual/Headers-and-Libraries) it says "All declarations needed to use GMP are collected in the include file gmp.h. It is designed to work with both C and C++ compilers." And I saw other examples using that header, so I assumed it was good to do so

Comment: I see, indeed that could have been clearer.